# How to make a video in background and other video in clip path (with animation) above it.? like this

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, video.js

So, I have a video in the background and another video running in clip-path in top of that video and the video in clip-path moving from left to right.
is CSS enough or do I need js ?
and how can I make a clip-path video?

[Like this](https://res.cloudinary.com/dvukj9sqf/video/upload/v1640662424/The_line_vamvwh.mov)

Comment: You might be able to do this with a CSS animation.  It might be a bit tricky though, as CSS doesn't know the video resolution.  Also, CSS will have no concept of synchronization that animation to the video playback.  If neither of these things are a problem, then you could do it in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

Set 1 video as a background.

And 1 video on the surface, then CSS the video class on the surface.

You can do it with CSS only I think, but it'll get a little bit tricky.

Or else with Javascript, just set the video on the surface some class, and when you refresh, hover, active, etc anything you need, that will trigger the class to active through, and the CSS of that class will be apply.

For example:

```
img {
    clip-path: circle(100%);
    transition: clip-path 5s;
}

img:hover{
    clip-path: circle(20%);
}
```

You can change the `img:hover` to however you like with your desire Class name or how you like to manipulate it. And the clip-path of yours to fully appear full of the width, I think that'll solve the problem.